# How to rerun TestNG failed tests via Maven command

Tags: java, maven, testing, testng

Basically the header says it all, imagine I ran a testsuite, now some of the test have failed and I want to rerun those tests. I know that there is `testng-failed.xml` file generated by surefire plugin but I don't know how to pass that file as a parameter to TestNG through Maven. This is what I tried but unfortunately none of these commands have worked (they run all the tests again).

```
mvn verify -DsuiteXmlFile=testng-failed.xml
mvn verify -DsuiteXmlFile=target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml
```

Comment: Are you running unit or integration tests? If you are running integration tests you should use the maven-failsafe-plugin instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are at the root of the project and it has a standard layout, you can run:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=target/surefire-reports/testng-failed.xml test
```

Comment: For me works correct with Surfire 2.21.0 and TestNG 6.11

Answer (score 0):

You should try the correct parameter which is [based on the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles)

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng-failed.xml
```

Comment: This doesn't work as well, I even moved the file to different folder and passed it to this parameter but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but for all who also stumble upon this question, [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) answer works if you add the appropriate maven lifecycle.

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=<path to testng-failed.xml> test
```